# Looking for a Postgresql community

Tags: postgresql

I need to learn about Postgresql. I'm trying to branch an application framework which is dependent on Oracle to use Postgresql. I can easily find communities of Java and JavaScript programmers via the web. Oracle communities a little more difficult, but between OTN and AskTom, I do pretty well. But Postgresql seems few and far between. Where do you go for Postgresql? Tutorials are useful too, but I'm hoping for a list or SO style site.

While SO is a great community, it is telling that the tags for this question have a combined usage of a only 155.  Not exactly a large group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the [Postgres newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.postgresql.general/topics)?
There's also [a community page](http://www.postgresql.org/community/) on the official Postgres website with links to IRC, forums, mailing lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

#postgresql on Freenode is very useful, there are also language-specific channels - check the community page which Don mentioned.